# Bound mismatch error on generics type argument for a generic class that extends another generic class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a problem with generics and inheritance in java.

I would like to instantiate an 'ObjectManager' class from the 'createManager' method that can create an instance from a given type. This 'ObjectManager' have some utility methods (ex: 'getDescription').

This method allows me to instantiate an 'ObjectManager' from a type and then get, for example, its description (the hash here).

I would also like to specialize 'ObjectManager' for 'FooManager' if the input type is assignable to type 'Foo', so that I can override the 'getDescription' method. I therefore test the type of the input in the 'createManager' method to know if I create an 'ObjectManager' or a 'FooManager'.

The code works, but I don't know the generic type for the output corresponding to 'new FooManager(type)'. In my opinion, and for Eclipse Quick fix, the type should be <T> but this leads to an error:

> Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Foo> of the type FooManager<T>

My code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class GenericBug {
    private GenericBug() {}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectManager<Foo> objectManager1 = createManager(Foo.class);
        System.out.println(objectManager1.getDescription());
        
        ObjectManager<Object> objectManager2 = createManager(Object.class);
        System.out.println(objectManager2.getDescription());
    }
    
    private static <T> ObjectManager<T> createManager(Class<T> type) {
        if(Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
            return new FooManager<T>(type);   //Error: Bound mismatch
        return new ObjectManager<T>(type);
    }
}

class ObjectManager<T>{
    public T val;
    public ObjectManager(Class<T> type) {
        try {
            val = type.getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Hash: " + Objects.hash(val);
    }
}

class FooManager<T extends Foo> extends ObjectManager<T>{

    public FooManager(Class<T> type) {
        super(type);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return super.getDescription() + " value: " + val.getVal();
    }
}

class Foo{
    private double val = Math.random();
    public Foo() {}

    public double getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

So my question is: why this error? how to fix it without having a warning? and, as a bonus, why Eclipse provides a solution that doesn't compile? is this an Eclipse error?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: you get this error because `FooManager` expects a type that extends `Foo`, but the `T` in `createFooManager()` doesn't do that "explicitly", it doesn't matter the check with `isAssignableFrom()`, from the compiler point of view, `T` in `createFooManager()` extends just `Object` hence the error.

Comment: One of the very first things I learned about OO, is that you know you're doing it wrong whenever you find yourself using _`if`_ statements to determine which object to instantiate.

Comment: Will your application only ever create instances of types _`Foo`_ and _`FooManager`_? What about objects of type _`Bar`_ that, semantically, are ***not*** _`Foos`_? Wouldn't you then need a corresponding _`BarManager`_? You'd then have to add another branch to your _`if`_ check. Right? To me, there is something sketchy about having a method named _`createFooManager()`_ be pressed into service to create things that, ***semantically*** have no _`Foo`_ -ness about them.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. I think I understood this warning, and it was the original objective.
Concerning the name of the method 'createFooManager', that was my mistake when creating this example...  It should be called 'createManager' as Eugene suggests. I will correct it in my example.

Comment: I also point out that I made this minimalist example to illustrate my problem. In reality, it is related to a problem of task delegation in a RMI context. I don't have just an if in my case, but rather a map that registers managers according to a type of class, and the user of my solution can add other managers dynamically. So I need a unique method to create it. In my opinion, this invalidates the deduper proposal, but he couldn't deduce it from my example... my bad...
Please note: sometimes I can also create managers without using this method, if I know which manager I want to use.

Comment: Thus, I have the feeling that I can't avoid these warnings at compile time, even if there is no problem at runtime.
I'm thinking of doing what John Angland suggests, adding a SuppressWarnings. Indeed, Eugene's solution also generates a warning and is more verbose.

Comment: to be fair, I would go for verbosity any time, but not for raw types; but this is just my opinion on the matter.

Comment: „*...I'm thinking of doing what John Angland suggests...*“ — Have you thought about doing what both @JohnAngland ***and*** deduper suggests: „*...If the class parameter is known at compile time, you could **simply call different methods for different classes**...*“? — „*...What I would infer from the inevitability of those warnings is that the initial approach is incorrect...*“ — Good point.

Comment: In my case, I don't know the class at compile time. I therefore can't call different methods. I agree with John Angland that when I call 'createManager', I'm not in a position to benefit from that generic parameter.

Comment: But ObjectManager has generic parameters for two reasons other reasons:
(1) Avoid casting the variable val in the line 'return super.getDescription() + " value: " + val.getVal();'. Without generic parameters, the type of val will be Object.
(2) Be used in other places without the use of 'createManager' but only with ObjectManager (because we don't need the specificity at these points) and be able to use the advantage of generic parameters. In my case, I only need the specificity at runtime and not during the editing phase.

Comment: Just to clarify in order to avoid misunderstanding. In my 'main', I call 'createManager' twice only to illustrate two cases of call. In reality, the 'createManager' method is called many times with different types and I don't know them in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error occurs because you have no compile time guarantee that T is an instance of Foo.  You have only the runtime guarantee that Foo is assignable from T, which the compiler does not care about.  You can literally make this compile without warnings by suppressing them:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private static <T> ObjectManager<T> createFooManager(Class<T> type) {
    if(Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
        return new FooManager(type);   //Error: Bound mismatch
    return new ObjectManager<T>(type);
}
```

That is probably not the answer you were looking for, but I don't think you can get rid of the warnings without suppressing them.  What I would infer from the inevitability of those warnings is that the initial approach is incorrect.  Why is it that you need to pass in a class as parameter?  If the class parameter is known at compile time, you could simply call different methods for different classes.  If the class is not known at compile time, you should never be in a position to benefit from that generic parameter at all.

Comment: I also posted my answer in my main post, but I also post it here:
In my case, I don't know the class at compile time. I therefore can't call different methods. I agree with you that when I call 'createManager', I'm not in a position to benefit from that generic parameter.

Comment: But ObjectManager has generic parameters for two reasons other reasons: (1) Avoid casting the variable val in the line 'return super.getDescription() + " value: " + val.getVal();'. Without generic parameters, the type of val will be Object. (2) Be used in other places without the use of 'createManager' but only with ObjectManager (because we don't need the specificity at these points) and be able to use the advantage of generic parameters. In my case, I only need the specificity at runtime and not during the editing phase.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing compile time safety of generics and runtime checks via `isAssignableFrom`.

I don't know of a better way to do it:

```
private static <T> ObjectManager<T> createFooManager(Class<T> type) {
    if (Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        return (ObjectManager<T>) getIt((Class<? extends Foo>) type);
    }
    return new ObjectManager<>(type);

}

private static <R extends Foo> ObjectManager<R> getIt(Class<R> cls) {
    return new FooManager<>(cls);
}
```

This will raise an `unchecked warning`, though.

Comment: Choosing which object to create, using an _`if`_ test is _typically_ considered a „_code smell_“ in object-oriented programming. Also, regarding: „_This will raise an unchecked warning, though_…“, my answer [_demonstrates how to avoid that_](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/2aOM).

Answer (score 1):

> „*…why this error?*…“

The error that *`javac`* reports on your original code gives you this reason:

```
...GenericBug.java:14: error: type argument T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2
            return new FooManager<T>(type);   //Error: Bound mismatch
                                  ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>createFooManager(Class<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Foo declared in class FooManager
1 error
```

*`T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2`* because:

1. *`<T> ObjectManager<T> createFooManager(...)`* means you defined *`T`* (*aka `T#1`*) as having ***no*** bounds.
2. The type parameter *`T`* (*aka`T#2`*) of *`FooManager<T extends Foo>`*  is defined with the bounds *`extends Foo`*. And the generic method's *`T`* does not extend *`Foo`* as the generic class requires. So it's *out of bounds*.

> „…*how to fix it*…“

Your original *`Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(type)`* approach strikes me as not very object-oriented. So basically, [*I've fixed it this way*](http://jdoodle.com/a/2aOM).

```
...
private static <T> ObjectManager<T> createObjectManager(Class<T> type) {
        return new ObjectManager<>(type);
} 

private static <S extends Foo> ObjectManager<S> createFooManager(Class<S> type) {
        return new FooManager<>(type);
}
...
```

It isn't obvious what your IRL use case is. So I had to make some assumptions. Like I assumed you would more than likely be using this with more specialized implementations of *`Foo`*. So I introduced a *`FooJr`* to demonstrate how the solution would deal with that:

```
    ObjectManager<? extends Foo> objectManager1 = createFooManager(Foo.class);
    System.out.println(objectManager1.getDescription());
    
    ObjectManager<?> objectManager2 = createObjectManager(Object.class);
    System.out.println(objectManager2.getDescription());

    objectManager1 = createFooManager(FooJr.class);
    System.out.println(objectManager1.getDescription());        

    objectManager2 = createObjectManager(FooJr.class);
    System.out.println(objectManager2.getDescription());
```

To say one solution is „*better*“ or „*worse*“ than another one is subjective; a matter of personal taste maybe. But it can be said with *objectivity* (*pun intended*) that one solution can be *more object-oriented* than another one. Some solutions are definitely more type safe than others.

> „…*without having a warning?*…“

[*This solution*](http://jdoodle.com/a/2aOM) is provably more type safe. Run it with *`-Xlint:unchecked`*. The compiler does not report any unchecked warnings. And that is without the need for any *`@SuppressWarnings(...)`*.

> „…*why Eclipse provides a solution that doesn't compile?*…“

Eclipse was only presenting you with its *best guess* at what it thought the fix for the problem was. It's in the nature of IDEs to give some things a PASS that *`javac`* or the JLS would absolutely not allow.

Comment: Often times, the „_better_“ solution — _in an OO design **best** practice context_ — is to create another method. Consider this: Will the application only ever create instances of types _`Foo`_ and _`FooManager`_? What about objects of type _`Bar`_ that, semantically, are ***not*** _`Foos`_? Wouldn't you then need a corresponding _`BarManager`_? To me, there is something sketchy about having a method named _`createFooManager()`_ be pressed into service to create things that, ***semantically*** have no _`Foo`_ -ness about them.

Comment: „_You just created a new method, this changes the contract of publicly exposed method that he/she would have to do_“ — The public API of the original _`createFooManager()`_ hasn't changed. So nothing would change for consumers of that method. My solution makes the application more type safe. ***AND*** it more closely follows OOD best practice to boot.

Comment: OP's method returns an _`ObjectManager<T>`_. Your answer's method returns an _`ObjectManager<T>`_. My answer's method returns an _`ObjectManager<S>`_. What's different? OP's method takes a _`Class<T>`_. My answer's method takes a _`Class<S>`_. No difference.  „_it means that callers are supposed to change, also_“ — Please? Show me — *with a small snippet of code* — in what way do callers have to change? I'm not objecting to your *review*. I'm (_1_) seeking knowledge (_2_) making sure the ***correct*** OO knowledge is out there for people like me who are seeking ***correct*** OO knowledge.

Comment: „*...OP method : `createObjectMapper` is called by two clients...*“— There was never an OP method named _`createObjectMapper()`_ nor an OP method named _`createObjectManager()`_. There was only ever _`createFooManager()`_. Don't take my word for it. Look at [_the revision history_](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62901445/revisions) yourself. — „*...You introduced a new method : `createFooManager` and edited the internals of `createObjectManager`...*“. That is what I mean by ***incorrect*** OO knowledge. I did not introduce _`createFooManager()`_. It was always there. See the post history?